# VBA use value to count columns avoiding activecell.column

Tags: vba, dimensions

I am trying to run a public value from starting the workbook to determine the column number to not use activecell.column. So I got:

```
Public CurrentColumn As Single
```

At the top outside the subroutine in ThisWorkbook and

```
CurrentColumn = ActiveCell.Column
```

inside the subroutine

Then I have buttons that are supposed to move to go left and right through columns and add or subtract 1 to the initial currentcolumn value.

```
CurrentColumn = CurrentColumn + 1
MsgBox CurrentColumn
```

But it seems that it doesn't actually add 1, because the message box shows "1" and that's not the correct column number because initial CurrentColumn is "3"

What am I doing wrong?

After this, I intend to replace

```
Worksheets("Machine Layout").Cells(9, ActiveCell.Column)
```

with something like

```
Worksheets("Machine Layout").Cells(9, CurrentColumn)
```

Could someone, please, help me figure this one out?

Comment: Is `CurrentColumn` meant to refer to the last column with data?

Comment: No, not really. It's meant to refer to active column. You see I have column "A" empty and column "B" filled with rows of different static parameters. After that there is dynamic data columns. Imagine PC specification parameters in "B" and actual specs in "C" "D" and however many configurations you may have for one PC case. And I have userform that can travel through those specs columns and add new ones. Initially currentcolumn value = 3 as taht's the first column with specs and upon clicking next, I need to +1 to that 3 and refer to column 4 in all my addresses

Comment: So is it the last column with data in the row?

Comment: No, it's "Current" column with data that may be in the range from column "C" to infinity

Comment: I need to avoid using activecell function, and I figure if I keep counting the active column from starting up the workbook - I could use that number in value address expressions like Worksheets("Machine Layout").Cells(9, ActiveCell.Column)

Comment: So basically I have one userform to fill however many specs columns there may be and then I can return to whichever column and edit it so CurrentColumn refers to activecolumn (selected one). But my userforms aren't symetrical in columns sense and userform might be filling one value to sheet1 column 4 and another to sheet2 column 5, but that column number may always be different for each case

Comment: And I have problems currently using activecell.column as I have to select the sheet prior to executing any code, and because it's all very complex, often it doesn't select the sheet I need, so I figure to hardwire the address of a cell in my code without selecting the worksheet pror

Comment: How do you determine which is the relevant column on each sheet? Randomly?

Comment: That's the idea - Upon starting a workbook I start currentcolumn = 3 and as I would click buttons to move to next or previous column - this currentcolumn number could go + or - 1 and I use that number in place of activecell.column

Comment: Setting arbitrary `CurrentColumn = 3` does something only if you follow it by setting the real current column. Something like `Cells(1, CurrentColumn).select`. In this way, the third column will be the correct referenced active column. But, if you try using it in more sheets, you must do it for the new  activated sheet, using `SheetActivate` event.

Comment: Yeah! But the problem is with modifying that currentcolumn value because CurrentColumn = CurrentColumn + 1 doesn't seem to actually make it 4, at least according to what a message box returns, as explained in the OP

Comment: Where `CurrentColumn` variable is declared? If `As Public`, on top of a **standard module** (in the declarations area) and **it is not declared again in a procedure**, it will certainly change its value. Please, check this aspects and send some feedback here.